# Conflicting overloads of global delete

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am attempting to write a a CLI interop layer between an existing c++ codebase and a c# wpf app. My c++ libraries already overload global new and delete in order to implement my own memory tracking and other niceties. So the dependencies look something like this:

(Native library compiled to static lib)->(CLI layer)->(C# WPF application)

However, whenever I include my native libraries and try and build my CLI project, I run into a conflicting symbol for global delete which was already defined in msvcrtd:

> Error  LNK2005 "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z) already defined in msvcrtd.lib(delete_scalar.obj)

I'm not sure how to get my build to take my global delete instead of the one in the default library. I have tried making another pure native project that compiles a DLL, and compiling all of my static libs into that, then having the interop layer load that DLL. This works, but I'd rather not have 2 layers of glue instead of the one.

I'm using visual studio 2015.

Comment: Memory tracking is nice but isn't overloading global new and delete a plain hack?

Answer (score 0):

The native component uses the CRT as DLL? This is requirement if using mixed assemblies. If you statically linked library uses the static CRT you get into troubles.

Check and link with the /VERBOSE flag to see, where this other delete comes from. Eliminate this other library call.